# PHP best way to salt a password in our time

Tags: php, hash, salt, saltedhash

How to make absolutely original salt for every user?
Is it better to use `time()` function in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many cases, a simple `uniqid(mt_rand(), true)` will do to generate a random salt. Combined with Blowfish should give you a pretty good password hash.

Alternatives are a pseudo random source such as `/dev/urandom` or `openssl_pseudo_random_bytes()`. There are also services that generate random data for you (based on radio-active degradation).

Comment: i think it is openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ( ) from [link](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)

Answer (score 3):

use this line to generate strong salt in php

```
 $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a *random* salt instead of non-random.. Maybe you will find something useful in this article http://www.gregboggs.com/php-blowfish-random-salted-passwords/

Also take a look at this article http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

One approach is to generate a unique salt for every user and store that salt in DB also.

Another good approach is that **algorithm, which generates hash of your password MUST calculate salt more than second**. The more complicated your hashing algorithm would be - the more problems will face a person who wants to hack your DB

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "MUST calculate salt more than second." Do you mean it should take longer than a second to execute? Please elaborate on this.

Comment: @nullability yes, longer than a second to execute

Answer (score 1):

You can use `microtime()` function in PHP to generate a number based on microsecond, not seconds which makes it almost impossible for a user to have a equal salt with another user. You can also multiply this number with the user's ID.

Maybe a `md5(uniqid())` is enough for salt for your application.

Edit: forgot to mention the more_entropy parameter with the `uniqid()` function. It will lesser the chances of same strings even when the function runs two times at the same microsecond, so the edited function should look like:

```
$salt = md5(uniqid($user_id, TRUE));
```